# Pre-populate Ember DS.Store via ajax

Tags: ajax, ember.js, store

Reading the Ember guide about the data store it's not clear how you pre-populate the store with your data.  I see you can set up the RESTadapter with the host name, and the 'store.find' method will trigger a 'get' request if the data is not cached, but how can I initialize a DS.Store with JSON data via ajax before ever doing a find?
[Ember guide model HTTP](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/)

The context for this is, a single page app that on page load gets a blob of json, which is used to model out the rest of the site.  The end result gives the illusion that the site contains multiple pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want `this.store.pushPayload(..)`

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_pushPayload

Note that you only have access to the store inside Routes and Controllers. Consider putting this inside the `activate` hook of `App.ApplicationRoute`

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_initial-routes
http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_activate